# Haskell operation "+" what does that mean?

Tags: haskell, operators

The code as follows:

```
chop [n] lev = [n-1]
chop (n:m:xs) lev = n-1:lev +m:xs
```

---

what does  `n-1:lev +m:xs` mean?
I know `m:xs` is list, how can a list add a int `(n-1:lev)`?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `(+)` associates more tightly than the `(:)` does. If we write that function with some more parentheses it'd be

```
chop [n]          lev = [n-1]
chop (n : m : xs) lev = (n-1) : (lev + m) : xs
```

So when the list has 2 or more elements `chop` modifies the first two. If it has just one element then only that one is modified.

Comment: `:i (+)` and `:i (:)` in ghci answers the "infixity" question; as a future reference for OP